# Как в tcpdf или подобной библиотеке вставить в pdf содержимое страницы, имея её url?

Tags: tcpdf, php

Как в tcpdf или подобной библиотеке вставить в pdf содержимое страницы, имея её url?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, конечно, слишком общий.
"Вставить страницу в PDF" из URL - это слишком неопределенно. Ведь не известно, что конкретно будет на странице.

Но в общем чертах про `tcpdf` сказать могу.

*Взять содержимое страницы, имея ее url* - для этого можно использовать стандартные функции `php`.
Проще всего, конечно, `file_get_contents();`

```
$thePage = file_get_contents([url]);
```

Теперь у Вас есть HTML страницы в переменной `$thePage`.
Далее создаете объект из класса `TCPDF` и используете шикарный метод `WriteHTML()`;

```
require_once(LIB_ROOT . 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); // подключаем библиотеку
$pdf = new TCPDF(); // создаем объект
$pdf->AddPage(); // первая страница
$pdf->writeHTML($thePage); // вставляем имеющийся текст в pdf
$pdf->Output($filename, 'I'); // выдаем результат на экран
```

---

Однако, совершенно не рекомендуется загонять в PDF страницы "как есть". CSS, наличие javascript, форматирование... Все это может повлиять на результат.
Без хоть какого-то анализа вытащенных из url данных никто не может Вам гарантировать результат.